# Filtering signal noise using Fourier Transforms and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, filter, signals, fft

So, I've been given three different MATLAB (I'm using MATLAB R2014b) files with signals containing noise. I simply just plotted the values I was given for the first part. For example, the plot of the first signal looks like the one below.

[image]

Then, I did the Fourier Transform of the signal and plotted those values as well to determine where the noise and signal occur in the frequency spectrum. To show this, I added the plot image of the first signal below.

[image]

Finally, I am supposed to create a filter using the basic MATLAB commands and filter the noise out of the plot of the signal and then do the Fourier Transform of the signal again and plot the results. The filter portion will look something like this...

```
b = fir1(n,w,'type');
freqz(b,1,512);
in = filter(b,1,in);
```

Where n is the order of the filter, w is the cutoff frequency (cutoff frequency divided by half the sampling rate), and 'type' is something to the effect of low/high/stop/etc... So, my question is how do I figure out what the n, w, and type values of the filter I am creating are supposed to be?! Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your high frequency components are *noise*, but it actually depends on your data.

See this example,

```
Fs = 2000;
L = 200;
t = (0 : L - 1)/Fs;
data = chirp(t,20,.05,50) + chirp(t,500,.1,700);
subplot(411)
plot(t,data,'LineWidth',2);
title('Original Data') 
N = 2^nextpow2(L);
y = fft(data,N)/L;
f = Fs/2 * linspace(0,1,N/2+1);
subplot(412)
plot(f,abs(y(1:N/2+1)))
title('Spectrum of Original Data')
b = fir1(40,2*[1 200]/Fs); 
newd = filter(b,1,data);
subplot(413)
plot(t,newd)
title('Filtered Data')
newy = fft(newd,N)/L;
subplot(414)
plot(f,abs(newy(1:N/2+1)))
title('Spectrum of Filtered Data')
```

[image]

You can use `b = fir1(40,2*[200 800]/Fs);` for high-pass filter.

Answer (score 1):

If the second plot is correct, in the x-axis, I can assume:

A. The sampling frequency is 2000 Hz.

B. The "noise" is in the low frequencies. It seems also from the original signal, that you need to filter the low-frequency baseline.

If so, you need highpass filter, so 'type'='high'.

The order is depend in the sharpness that you want to the filter. from the plots it seems that you can use 'n'=12 or 20.

The cutoff frequency suppose to be about 0.1 if the peak in the low frequencies is indeed the noise that you want to filter, and if the 1000Hz x-axis is indeed the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Ahh, so I understand just about everything you are saying perfectly, except for the cutoff frequency. It needs to be 0.1 of what exactly.  Right now I have this, `b = fir1(20,100/(2000/2),'high');  freqz(b,1,512);  in = filter(b,1,in);`  I just don't understand what the cutoff frequency needs to actually be. It almost gives me a smooth plot when using this code, though.

Comment: Is that filtered enough?

Comment: I don't know. Look at your time-signal- Is it filtered enough? Is it too much filtered? It depends on your requirements...